# Content types disappear

Tags: views, nodes, rules, search

In some lists my content types all disappear. This especially affects Apache Solr for me. But also Views and Rules dont show the content types in some lists.

Interesting is that:

1. One content type is shown("Rezept") which is created by a custom module
2. All content types are shown correctly the moment i clear the cache.

**Views:**

[image: Views not showing content types]

**Apache Solr Module:**

[image: Solr not showing content types]

The moment i clear the cache they show up correctly. But as soon as the cache clearing is finished and i reload the page, they disappear again:

**Views while clearing the cache:**

[image: Views showing all content types]

**Apache Solr while clearing the cache:**

[image: Solr showing all content types]

Comment: Maybe a good idea to include how you're defining your custom content type(s) in the module as could be related.

Comment: The module has been created by a third developer. What informations do you need exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was caused by Domain Access Module. Since i didnt needed it anymore, i deactivated it.